Enabling one URL behind router, while keeping the rest disabled
I have an IP camera software running and I can get access to it from the outside.
However, on that webserver, there is an admin interface that I don't want exposed.
I tried to create a website under my contron, that would show the video stream, but wouldn't provide access to the admin part. That worked - but only works on my local network.
So I would like to explore ways to:
mydomain:myport/video is accessible from the internet
mydomain:myport followed by everything else, including nothing is not accessible from the internet.
You guys are smart and I am not - this usually results into advice that is useless to me. So I would like to save everyones time and ask you to not provide me with a solution to this, but with a question I should be asking. Because I can't put together even that.
Thank you very much
